# isalpha python function won't consider spaces

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

So the code below takes an input and makes sure the input consists of letters and not numbers. How would i make it also print orginal if the input contains a space

```
original = raw_input("Type the name of the application: ")

if original.isalpha() and len(original) > 0:
    print original
else:
    print "empty"
```

tried this code but worked when the input was a number too.

```
original = raw_input("Type the word you want to change: ")

if original.isalpha() or len(original) > 0:
    print original
else:
    print "empty"
```

Comment: Can the input have no numbers or it can't consist of only numbers?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It looks like that's just how string works.

Two options:

```
if all(x.isalpha() or x.isspace() for x in original):
```

(modified on inspectorG4dget's recommendation below)

or

```
original.replace(' ','').isalpha()
```

should work.

Comment: I would suggest the former over the latter, just so you don't modify original if you want to use that later.

Comment: I would have gone with `all(isalpha(x) or isspace(x) for x in original)`

Comment: @Cyber: `original.replace` doesn't modify original. It returns a new string

Comment: @Cyber - The second one does not modify `original` - strings are always immutable. @inspectorG4dget - yeah, that's probably more concise, i'll modify

Comment: `isalpha` and `isspace` are *methods*, not functions.