# How do I use isalpha() and isspace()

Tags: python

I am trying to return a yes or no answer to show whether the string has spaces or letters. The bolded part is the part I need to get right. I got the other parts...

Here is what I have put and it doesn't work out correctly...

```
if (string.isalpha() and string.isspace()):
    print('Only alphabetic letters and spaces: yes')
else:
    print('Only alphabetic letters and spaces: no')
```

How can I use them together? I know how to do this separately but not together. I know this may seem really simple but I am a beginner.

example of the program----

Enter a string: please open my email

Length: 20

First character: p

Last character: l

Contains open: yes

**Only alphabetic letters and spaces: yes**

Only numeric digits: no

All lower case: yes

All upper case: no

Comment: What string will return `True` for both `isalpha()` _and_ `isspace()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890618/isalpha-python-function-wont-consider-spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're testing the whole string. You should be testing each character individually.

```
is_alpha_or_space = all(c.isalpha() or c.isspace() for c in string)
```

Comment: I see what you mean here but what if the string does not contain both letters and spaces? How do I make it work to use the else statement print('Only alphabetic letters and spaces: no').
It keeps saying yes even if it is not true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `or` and `all` to check **each letter**:

```
if all(char.isalpha() or char.isspace() for char in string):
    print('Only alphabetic letters and spaces: yes')
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

```
if all(x.isalpha() or x.isspace() for x in original):
```

or

```
original.replace(' ','').isalpha()
```

should work.

Answer (score -2):

You can try changing the condition to `str(input.isspace() and input.isalpha())`